# vsftpd OS X chroot_local_user doesn't work

Tags: macos, ftp, vsftpd

I set up a vsftpd on my OS X, it's ok but I can't connect on this.
I have "530: Login inccorect" with my OS X user.

On a Linux server, it's ok, but I don't understand why doesn't works on mac.

My vsftpd.conf

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
listen=YES
local_umask=022
#anon_upload_enable=YES
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=whoever
xferlog_file=/opt/local/var/log/vsftpd.log
xferlog_std_format=YES
#idle_session_timeout=600
#data_connection_timeout=120
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure
#async_abor_enable=YES
#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES
ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
#deny_email_enable=YES
#banned_email_file=/opt/local/etc/vsftpd.banned_emails
chroot_local_user=YES
#chroot_list_enable=YES
#chroot_list_file=/opt/local/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
#ls_recurse_enable=YES
listen=YES
#listen_ipv6=YES
pam_service_name=ftp
listen_port=3434
```

Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the "`local_enable=YES`", you can login as local users.
When you login ftp as local users, it will automatically check your input username and password, and it will check from the file `/etc/passwd`.
Here's the problem:

Instead of Linux, in Mac OS X, all your users exists on your laptop does not stored in the file `/etc/passwd`.

So you cannot login ftp as a local user on your Mac.

I only know this. I don't know how to fix it, either.